# Add text between multiple lines with sed if previous line does not match pattern

Tags: sed, regular-expression, html

I'm struggling to add `<dl>` tags around a definition list with sed, and perhaps there is an easier way to do it (I'd love to know).

I would like to search a file for any lines that contain a `<dt>`, but only match if the previous line does *not* contain `<dt>` or `<dd>`. When a match is found, insert a `<dl>`.

My attempt so far (which doesn't match at all):

```
sed '/^((?!<dt>).)*$/ {
    N
    /<dt>/ {
        s/<dt>/<dl><dt>/
    } 
}' file
```

And the file

````
# TODO #

 * Set up mail transfer agent
 * Reconfigure timezone

```bash
dpkg-reconfigure tzdata
```

# Hardware #
  <dt>RAM</dt>
  <dd>2GB</dd>

# Partitions #

<dt>`/dev/sda1`</dt>
<dd>/boot</dd>
<dt>`/dev/sda2`</dt>
<dd>/</dd>
````

The purpose of all of this is to write a parser that converts moinmoin wiki markup to markdown, for porting to a new wiki engine. The defintion list is currently made with the following rule:

```
sed -i 's/^ \(.*\):: \(.*\)$/  <dt>\1<\/dt>\n  <dd>\2<\/dd>/' file
```

I would like the output to look like this:

````
# TODO #

 * Set up mail transfer agent
 * Reconfigure timezone

```bash
dpkg-reconfigure tzdata
```

# Hardware #
<dl>
  <dt>RAM</dt>
  <dd>2GB</dd>
</dl>

# Partitions #

<dl>
<dt>`/dev/sda1`</dt>
<dd>/boot</dd>
<dt>`/dev/sda2`</dt>
<dd>/</dd>
</dl>
````

Note that I'd like valid html as much as possible. There needs to be a closing tag for each opening tag.

Comment: ok, but all of you lines match the pattern. is there any way you could provide a *(only slightly)* more realistic example input and to complement it with a an example of your desired output? it just makes it more simple - less guessing.

Comment: I've expanded the example file - sorry about that.

Comment: so you should wrap every pair of sequential `<dt>...</dt>\n<dd>...</dt>\n` tags within another pair of `<dl>...</dl>` or an entire sequence of pairs be enclosed?

Comment: An entire sequence of pairs should be enclosed. I've added the desirable output as a demo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This may be more `sed` than you expect, but I think this is the best way to accomplish what you want with `sed`.

This script:

- Inserts a line `<dl>` before each line that contains a `<dt>`, if no other `<dt>`, `<dd>`, or `<dl>` preceded the line.
- Appends a line `</dl>` after each line containing `<dd>`, if the line after the line containing `<dd>` does not contain `<dd>`.

This `sed` script uses the `sed` `hold` space to remember the previous line so it can be checked for the `<d[tdl]>` tags before inserting the `<dl>` tag.  It also uses relative addressing `ADDR,+N` to allow adding the closing `</dl>` tag.  A special case is required to detect if a `<dd>` is on the last line of the file and needs an appended `</dl>`.  Testing (`t` and `T`) and branching (`b`) are used extensively to implement the logic.

```
#!/bin/sh

sed '
    /<dt>/ {
        x                  # exchange pattern and hold space
        s/<d[tdl]>//       # subsitutue, just testing for pattern
        g                  # copy hold space back, overwriting pattern space
        t end              # branch to :end if previous subsitution successful
        i \
<dl>
    }

    $ {
        /<dd>/ ! b end     # if <dd> on last line, append </dl>
        a \
</dl>
    }

    /<dd>/,+1 {            # on each line containing <dd> and the line after
        /<dd>/ b end       # if does not contain <dd>, insert </dl>
        i \
</dl>
    }

:end
    h                      # copy pattern space to hold space for next round

' "$@"
```

This script modifies the sample data to look like this:

```
[...]

# Hardware #
<dl>
  <dt>RAM</dt>
  <dd>2GB</dd>
</dl>

# Partitions #

<dl>
<dt>`/dev/sda1`</dt>
<dd>/boot</dd>
<dt>`/dev/sda2`</dt>
<dd>/</dd>
</dl>
```

Comment: ahh! so wrapped all the way around then! what do you do if you have a validly positioned `<dt>...</dt>` pair but which is not followed by a validly positioned `<dd>...</dd>` pair?

Comment: This script as written won't put out the `</dl>` except after a `<dd>`.

Comment: thats probably correct - i dunno. i would consider it more correct than the other way - but i dunno know how all that tag stuff works. its why i asked *(you and the asker)* - i wanna do an answer. thank you. oh. but - well - you mean you possibly do the `<dl>` without the `</dl>`? i dunno about that.... hm. well. youve got my vote already anyway. shucks. in truth - i didnt even consider the ramifications of that - just that i didnt know if the `</dl>` should go *before* the trailing `<dt>`...

Comment: The tags are `<dl>`: definition list, `<dt>` definition term, `<dd>` definition data (or definition). I think they want to wrap the `<dt>/<dd>` sequences with `<dl>`.  On fragments of `html` in a wiki, we don't really need to be too concerned with the greater `xml/html` context/validity.  So I scripted this to the given input data.  If there's a case of `<dt>` not folowed by `<dd>`, that would require changes, though it's completely doable. If the answers handle cases not in the sample data, I think it gets too complex and confusing.  I hope that helps.

Comment: Outstanding. Thanks for the comments as well, I had no idea about the branch thing in sed.